# push to the top leaving middle two commits

Tags: git, github, commit, git-push, git-commit

Let's say I have following commits

`cccc[recent]`

`bbbb`

`aaaa`

Now I have bugs in `cccc` and I have rolled back to `aaaa` by

`git reset --hard aaaa`

and I have worked here,this all happened in `bugs` branch

Now when I try to push the cmmits to the `bugs` branch it is telling

```
! [rejected]        bugs -> bugs (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'my url'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I want to push my changes and remove the `bbbb` and 'cccc` commits.

how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already pushed it you should do a [git revert](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) instead of a forced push

```
$ git revert cccc
$ git revert bbbb
```

This will leave the commits `cccc` and `bbbb` in the history and introduces new commits on top of them that revert the changes.

```
o-----o-----o-----o-----o
^     ^     ^     ^     ^
|     |     |     |     |
aaaa  bbbb  cccc  cccc' bbbb'
```

If you want revert `bbbb` and `cccc` in one commit do

```
$ git revert --no-commit bbbb
$ git revert --no-commit cccc
$ git commit -m 'Reverted commit bbbb and cccc'
```

If you want to revert the changes by doing a forced push

```
$ git reset --hard aaaa
$ git push -f
```

you should make sure that no other developer has already made commits on top of `bbbb` or `cccc`.

Comment: Nice, clear answer, I will delete mine as this explains reverting in a lot more detail